# "survival" doesnt show in my survfit function in R

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

I am trying to calculate the 5 year overall survival in my dataset.
I have used the `survival` package in `r`.

Here is my code:
`summary(survfit(Surv(finaldate,TOD5) ~1, data = hansccses), times = 5)`

This is my output though:

```
 time n.risk n.event  P(1)   P()
    5   1265    7158 0.554 0.446
```

I get the same thing when I take out `times=5`

I am trying to get something like this:

```
>summary(survfit(Surv(time, status)~1))

Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ 1)

 time  n.risk  n.event  survival   std.err   lower 95% CI upper 95% CI

    5     23       2        0.9130   0.0588       0.8049        1.000

    8     21       2        0.8261   0.0790       0.6848        0.996
```

Comment: It might be the $\sim 1$ that you have in your code. If you are willing to share your data I should be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comment made me see it. I added ```TOD5 == 1``` and it worked!